# Is there a way for Flutter for web to hide ios safari's url bar and bottom navigation bar on scroll

Tags: flutter, mobile-safari, flutter-web

iOS Safari's default is usually to hide the url bar and bottom navigation bar on webpage scroll.
However, maybe due to how Flutter for web render things, Safari currently does not hide both the url bar and bottom navigation bar on scroll.

I'm wondering if there is any workaround for this?